# Use the most recent record's value in query

Tags: mysql

I have a database with the following 3 tables:

### major

```
id_major 
major_name
```

### major_year

```
id_major 
id_year
```

### year

```
id_year 
year
```

I'm using the following select statement to retrieve the relevant data:

```
SELECT * FROM major m
     JOIN major_year mj
       ON m.id_major=mj.id_major
     JOIN year y
       ON mj.id_year=y.id_year
WHERE y.id_year="?"
```

I want to specify the most recent `y.id_year` automatically, so what do I use in place of the `?` in my query?

Comment: use max(year) which will always select the latest year in the table

Comment: As a note, I suggest you rename your primary key fields to `id` (your join table could use `year_id` and `major_id`): it would tidy up your query (e.g., `m.id=mj.major_id`, etc.) and since you're specifying the database anyway, the extra text (i.e. `_year`) is redundant.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your new id_year is on the basis of MAX(id_year). Try this

```
select top 1 from major m 
    join major_year mj 
      on m.id_major=mj.id_major 
    join year y 
      on mj.id_year=y.id_year 
order by y.id_year desc
```